# Passing output of rsync command into notification message (on macOS)

Tags: shell-script, command-substitution, macos

Probably, this is a general unix question and therefore not restricted to macOS.
I would like to output the output of my rsync command as a notification message. But I don't succeed in placing the variable correctly. If my code is like this:

```
RSYNC1="$(rsync --itemize-changes -avz -e ssh \
/Users/user/ server:/home/backup/ --delete)" && \
osascript -e 'display notification "${RSYNC1}" with title "Backup"'
```

then ${RSYNC1} is just printed literlly, and if I escape the quotes like this

```
osascript -e 'display notification \"${RSYNC1}\" with title "Backup"'
```

then this error is given:

```
> 21:22: syntax error: „given“, „in“, „of“, experssion, „with“,
> „without“, other parameter name, etc. expected, but unknown token
> found. (-2741)
```

What do I have to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use double quotes to get variable expansion. To print literal double quotes inside double quotes you have to escape them:

```
osascript -e "display notification \"${RSYNC1}\" with title \"Backup\""
```

Alternatively, use single quotes when inside the double quotes:

```
osascript -e "display notification '${RSYNC1}' with title 'Backup'"
```